# how to create a submit button in a modal?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have created a normal

```
= simple_form_for @nacform, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|


  = f.error_notification

  .row
    .span12
      %h4 Form Details
      %hr
  .row
    .span3
      .field
        = f.input :Title
      .field
        = f.input :Description
      .field
        = f.label :asset, "File"
        = f.file_field :asset
  .form-actions

    = link_to 'Back', nacforms_path, :class => 'btn btn-small btn-primary'
    %a#modal_btn.btn.btn-success.btn-small{:href => "#modal"} Continue
```

and the modal

```
#modal.modal.hide
    .about
      .modal-header
        %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} &times;
        %h2 Forms
    = simple_form_for @nacform, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
      = f.button :submit, "Upload Form", :class => 'btn btn-success'

:javascript
    $("#modal_btn").click(function(){
      $('#modal').modal();
    });
```

the submit button for the form is on the modal, but when i click on that submit button nothing happens, Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Sounds a bit overcomplicated.  Why not just make a hidden submit button on the page and have a link that clicks through to that via javascript?

Answer (score 0):

In order for things to appear using jQuery [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method or something derived from it, you generally specify an inline style that's easy to override:

```
#modal.modal{ :style => 'display:none' }
```

Having a `.hide` CSS class may be what's causing it to stay hidden.